# Java: network settings window

Tags: java, swing

I'm looking for a way to program textfields with dots like the one from Windows network settings dialog:

see >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/gayeY.jpg

Is there any ready-to-use example on the net? - unfortunately I didn't find anything.

Thanks a lot for your help!

-patrick

Answer (score 2):

With the help of a simple google search i found [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html), here's an [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) on how to use it.

---

IP-address example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException  
{ 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    JTextField f = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("###.###.###.###"));
    f.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    frame.add(f);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(100, 50);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks go to dacwe for the example.

Answer (score 2):

As previously discussed on Stack Overflow (see [How do I set the value of a JFormattedTextField with a placeholder character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976304/how-do-i-set-the-value-of-a-jformattedtextfield-with-a-placeholder-character)), you can't easily use the JFormattedTextField to input IP addresses. However, there is also the RegexFormatter from Sun (see http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/reftf/; download the source code at http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/reftf/RegexFormatter.java) which you can use like this:

```
   JFormattedTextField ipAddress;
   try{
    RegexFormatter ipmask = new RegexFormatter("\\d{0,3}\\.\\d{0,3}\\.\\d{0,3}\\.\\d{0,3}");
        ipmask.setOverwriteMode(false);
    ipAddress = new JFormattedTextField(ipmask);
}catch(Exception e1){
}
ipAddress.setValue("255.255.255.255");
```

This will let you enter/edit the value and preserve the dots in the output.

Comment: Nice. I have used `RegexFormatter ipmask = new RegexFormatter("\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}");` and `ipAddress.setValue("...");` However, the MaskFormatter has better behaviour - it prevents the user to set incorrect characters;